# Display math gets typeset as inline math

Tags: math-mode, arrays, inline, mathtools, displaystyle

When typesetting the below annotated equation my summations are being typeset as inline maths rather than display maths.
[image: Inline sumations, curse you!]

- If I wrap the sum and subscript with `\smashoperator{}` then they are typeset correctly as display math again.
- I've tried multiple outermost wrappers for the array of arrays,

  - `\begin{equation}`,
  - `\begin{align}` starred and unstarred,
  - `\[ ... \]`,
  - `\begin{gather}`.

I'm aware of the existance of the `\displaystyle` macro, I don't want to set it globally if at all posible, I have inline maths elsewhere in my document. In all honesty I'd like to find out what I'm doing wrong and fix that rather than stick a macro in there to fix my poor tex-ing).

I compile my document with `LuaLaTeX`, MWE follows.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
   \begin{equation}
   \begin{array}{ll} % array to ensure the force field and the braces are aligned, as the non-bonded terms are a little wider than the bonded.
      \begin{array}{rcl} % bonded terms.
         U  &=& \sum_{\text{bonds},\, i} K_{b,i} \left( b_i - b_{0,i} \right)^2 \\
            &+& \sum_{\text{angles},\, i} K_{\theta,i} \left( \theta_i - \theta_{0,i} \right)^2 \\
            &+& \sum_{\text{dihedrals},\, i}%
               K_{\phi,i} \left( 1 - \cos\left( n\phi_i - \phi_{0,i} \right) \right) \\
            &+& \sum_{%
               \substack{\text{improper},\, i\\ \text{dihedrals}}%
               } K_{\omega,i} \left( \omega_i - \omega_{0,i} \right)^2 \\
   \end{array}%
   & \left. \vphantom{% Phantom content to make brace correct size. \left. \right\} Havent worked when across two columns in array...
               \begin{array}{rcl}
                  U  &=& \sum_{\text{bonds},\, i} K_{b,i} \left( b_i - b_{0,i} \right)^2 \\
                     &+& \sum_{\text{angles},\, i} K_{\theta,i} \left( \theta_i - \theta_{0,i} \right)^2 \\
                     &+& \sum_{\text{dihedrals},\, i}%
                        K_{\phi,i} \left( 1 - \cos\left( n\phi_i - \phi_{0,i} \right) \right) \\
                     &+& \sum_{%
                        \substack{\text{improper},\, i\\ \text{dihedrals}}%
                        } K_{\omega,i} \left( \omega_i - \omega_{0,i} \right)^2 \\
               \end{array}
               }%
   \right\} \text{bonded} \\
   \begin{array}{rcl} % non-bonded terms.
      \hphantom{U}   &+& \sum_{\text{atoms},\, i,j} \epsilon_{ij}%
                        \left[%
                           \left(%
                              \frac{ r^{min}_{ij} } { r_{ij} }%
                           \right)^{12}%
                           -2 \left(%
                              \frac{ r^{min}_{ij} }{ r_{ij} }%
                           \right)^6%
                        \right] \\
                     &+& \sum_{\text{atoms},\, i,j}%
                        \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0\epsilon_r}\frac{q_i q_j}{ r_{ij} }
   \end{array}%
   & \left. \vphantom{% Phantom content to make brace correct size. \left. \right\} Havent worked when across two columns in array...
               \begin{array}{rcl} % non-bonded terms.
                  \phantom{U} &+& \sum_{\text{atoms},\, i,j} \epsilon_{ij}%
                                 \left[%
                                    \left(%
                                       \frac{ r^{min}_{ij} } { r_{ij} }%
                                    \right)^{12}%
                                    -2 \left(%
                                       \frac{ r^{min}_{ij} }{ r_{ij} }%
                                    \right)^6%
                                 \right] \\
                              &+& \sum_{\text{atoms},\, i,j}%
                                 \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0\epsilon_r}\frac{q_i q_j}{ r_{ij} }
               \end{array}
               }%
   \right\} \text{non-bonded}
   \end{array}
   \end{equation}

\lipsum[2-3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you really want to do that with arrays, you could load the `array` package and do `\begin{array}{rc>{\displaystyle}l}`

Comment: @LaRiFaRi That's a good suggestion, I already use `array` to define new column types for elsewhere in the document. I'm not attached to the array environment here, just the alignment I've achieved with it. If another suggestion comes up without using `\begin{array}` I'll look at that too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add `\displaystyle` to the columns you like in your `array`:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    \begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
    &\left.\begin{array}{r@{\;}>{{}\displaystyle}l}
    U  =& \sum_{\mathclap{\text{bonds},\,i}} K_{b,i} ( b_i - b_{0,i})^2 \\
    &+ \sum_{\mathclap{\text{angles},\, i}} K_{\theta,i} ( \theta_i - \theta_{0,i} )^2 \\
    &+ \sum_{\mathclap{\text{dihedrals},\, i}}  K_{\phi,i} \bigl( 1 - \cos( n\phi_i - \phi_{0,i} ) \bigr) \\
    &+ \mathrlap{\sum_{\mathclap{\substack{\text{improper},\, i\\ \text{dihedrals}}}} K_{\omega,i} ( \omega_i - \omega_{0,i} )^2 }
    \hphantom{\sum_{\mathclap{\text{atoms},\,i,j}}\epsilon_{ij}\Biggl[\biggl(\frac{r^{\min}_{ij}}{r_{ij}}\biggr)^{12}-2\biggl(\frac{r^{\min}_{ij}}{r_{ij}}\biggr)^6\Biggr]}
    \end{array}\right\}\text{bonded}\\
    &\left.\begin{array}{r@{\;}>{{}\displaystyle}l}
    \hphantom{U =}
    &+\sum_{\mathclap{\text{atoms},\,i,j}}\epsilon_{ij}\Biggl[\biggl(\frac{r^{\min}_{ij}}{r_{ij}}\biggr)^{12}-2\biggl(\frac{r^{\min}_{ij}}{r_{ij}}\biggr)^6\Biggr] \\
    &+\sum_{\mathclap{\text{atoms},\, i,j}}(4\pi\epsilon_0\epsilon_r)^{-1}\frac{q_i q_j}{ r_{ij}}
    \end{array}\right\}\text{non-bonded}
    \end{aligned}
    \end{equation}
    \lipsum[2-3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you were just concerned about the limits of your sum-symbols, you could add the command `\limits` to each of them. Safes you some space.

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\left.\begin{array}{r@{\;}>{{}}l}
U =&\sum\limits_{\mathclap{\text{bonds},\,i}} K_{b,i} ( b_i - b_{0,i})^2 \\
&+ \sum\limits_{\mathclap{\text{angles},\, i}} K_{\theta,i} ( \theta_i - \theta_{0,i} )^2 \\
&+ \sum\limits_{\mathclap{\text{dihedrals},\, i}}   K_{\phi,i}\bigl( 1 - \cos( n\phi_i - \phi_{0,i} ) \bigr) \\
&+ \mathrlap{\sum\limits_{\mathclap{\substack{\text{improper},\, i\\ \text{dihedrals}}}} K_{\omega,i} ( \omega_i - \omega_{0,i} )^2 }
\hphantom{\sum\limits_{\mathclap{\text{atoms},\,i,j}}\epsilon_{ij}\biggl[\Bigl(\frac{r^{\min}_{ij}}{r_{ij}}\Bigr)^{12}-2\Bigl(\frac{r^{\min}_{ij}}{r_{ij}}\Bigr)^6\biggr]}
\end{array}\right\}\text{bonded}\\
&\left.\begin{array}{r@{\;}>{{}}l}
\hphantom{U =}
&+\sum\limits_{\mathclap{\text{atoms},\,i,j}}\epsilon_{ij}\biggl[\Bigl(\frac{r^{\min}_{ij}}{r_{ij}}\Bigr)^{12}-2\Bigl(\frac{r^{\min}_{ij}}{r_{ij}}\Bigr)^6\biggr] \\
&+\sum\limits_{\mathclap{\text{atoms},\, i,j}}(4\pi\epsilon_0\epsilon_r)^{-1}\frac{q_i q_j}{ r_{ij}}
\end{array}\right\}\text{non-bonded}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

This would look like

[image]

---

However, personally I would not set such things as an `array`, as those are meant for matrices and alike. You could just nest two `aligned` which will result in display style as well.

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\left.\begin{aligned}
U  ={}& \sum_{\mathclap{\text{bonds},\,i}} K_{b,i} ( b_i - b_{0,i})^2 \\
&+ \sum_{\mathclap{\text{angles},\, i}} K_{\theta,i} ( \theta_i - \theta_{0,i} )^2 \\
&+ \sum_{\mathclap{\text{dihedrals},\, i}}  K_{\phi,i} \bigl( 1 - \cos( n\phi_i - \phi_{0,i} ) \bigr) \\
&+ \mathrlap{\sum_{\mathclap{\substack{\text{improper},\, i\\ \text{dihedrals}}}} K_{\omega,i} ( \omega_i - \omega_{0,i} )^2 }
\hphantom{\sum_{\mathclap{\text{atoms},\,i,j}}\epsilon_{ij}\Biggl[\biggl(\frac{r^{\min}_{ij}}{r_{ij}}\biggr)^{12}-2\biggl(\frac{r^{\min}_{ij}}{r_{ij}}\biggr)^6\Biggr]}
\end{aligned}\right\}\text{bonded}\\
&\left.\begin{aligned}
\hphantom{U ={}}
&+\sum_{\mathclap{\text{atoms},\,i,j}}\epsilon_{ij}\Biggl[\biggl(\frac{r^{\min}_{ij}}{r_{ij}}\biggr)^{12}-2\biggl(\frac{r^{\min}_{ij}}{r_{ij}}\biggr)^6\Biggr] \\
&+\sum_{\mathclap{\text{atoms},\, i,j}}(4\pi\epsilon_0\epsilon_r)^{-1}\frac{q_i q_j}{ r_{ij}}
\end{aligned}\right\}\text{non-bonded}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

You can see that the vertical spacing is much more pleasant (but you could treat that manually for all cases, of course):

[image]

Comment: Excellent. +1 for the no-array version from me too. I'd gone away overnight and done much the same thing with nested `\begin{aligned}` environments, but this is done better. I forgot to check that I could seperate `\left.` and `\right\{` by alignments characters (`&`) now that I'd gotten rid of pesky `array`'s The way it's done here minimises `\*phantom` spacing, and still gets the nice alignment of the equation *and* the descriptive braces.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a general option which addresses your concern. That is, a localized change from inline to display style mathematical typesetting. The easier option for the case you're using `array` is adjusting the argument thereof (as mentioned in the comments).

The solution opens a group, and redefines the macros you wish to be `\displaystyle`. After the group closes the redefinitions are also reset.

In your case, you may need to readjust the arraystretch to make sure no symbols overlap between lines. (`\renewcommand\arraystretch{<factor>}` somewhere between `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`).

Here's a screenshot from the output. Notice how the inline math below the array has the "standard inline" math style.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begingroup
\let\oldsum\sum
\let\oldfrac\frac
\def\sum{\displaystyle\oldsum}
\def\frac{\displaystyle\oldfrac}
   \begin{equation}
   \begin{array}{ll} % array to ensure the force field and the braces are aligned, as the non-bonded terms are a little wider than the bonded.
      \begin{array}{rcl} % bonded terms.
         U  &=& \sum_{\text{bonds},\, i} K_{b,i} \left( b_i - b_{0,i} \right)^2 \\
            &+& \sum_{\text{angles},\, i} K_{\theta,i} \left( \theta_i - \theta_{0,i} \right)^2 \\
            &+& \sum_{\text{dihedrals},\, i}%
               K_{\phi,i} \left( 1 - \cos\left( n\phi_i - \phi_{0,i} \right) \right) \\
            &+& \sum_{%
               \substack{\text{improper},\, i\\ \text{dihedrals}}%
               } K_{\omega,i} \left( \omega_i - \omega_{0,i} \right)^2 \\
   \end{array}%
   & \left. \vphantom{% Phantom content to make brace correct size. \left. \right\} Havent worked when across two columns in array...
               \begin{array}{rcl}
                  U  &=& \sum_{\text{bonds},\, i} K_{b,i} \left( b_i - b_{0,i} \right)^2 \\
                     &+& \sum_{\text{angles},\, i} K_{\theta,i} \left( \theta_i - \theta_{0,i} \right)^2 \\
                     &+& \sum_{\text{dihedrals},\, i}%
                        K_{\phi,i} \left( 1 - \cos\left( n\phi_i - \phi_{0,i} \right) \right) \\
                     &+& \sum_{%
                        \substack{\text{improper},\, i\\ \text{dihedrals}}%
                        } K_{\omega,i} \left( \omega_i - \omega_{0,i} \right)^2 \\
               \end{array}
               }%
   \right\} \text{bonded} \\
   \begin{array}{rcl} % non-bonded terms.
      \hphantom{U}   &+& \sum_{\text{atoms},\, i,j} \epsilon_{ij}%
                        \left[%
                           \left(%
                              \frac{ r^{min}_{ij} } { r_{ij} }%
                           \right)^{12}%
                           -2 \left(%
                              \frac{ r^{min}_{ij} }{ r_{ij} }%
                           \right)^6%
                        \right] \\
                     &+& \sum_{\text{atoms},\, i,j}%
                        \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0\epsilon_r}\frac{q_i q_j}{ r_{ij} }
   \end{array}%
   & \left. \vphantom{% Phantom content to make brace correct size. \left. \right\} Havent worked when across two columns in array...
               \begin{array}{rcl} % non-bonded terms.
                  \phantom{U} &+& \sum_{\text{atoms},\, i,j} \epsilon_{ij}%
                                 \left[%
                                    \left(%
                                       \frac{ r^{min}_{ij} } { r_{ij} }%
                                    \right)^{12}%
                                    -2 \left(%
                                       \frac{ r^{min}_{ij} }{ r_{ij} }%
                                    \right)^6%
                                 \right] \\
                              &+& \sum_{\text{atoms},\, i,j}%
                                 \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0\epsilon_r}\frac{q_i q_j}{ r_{ij} }
               \end{array}
               }%
   \right\} \text{non-bonded}
   \end{array}
   \end{equation}
\endgroup
$\sum_{\text{bonds},\, i} K_{b,i} \left( b_i - b_{0,i} \right)^2$
\lipsum[2-3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hmm, I like the re-definition of the `\sum` and `\frac` commands. As far as I can see the outermost environment should be a *display*-type environment already, so I don't see why my original code should be typesetting maths in *inline* mode in the first place.

Comment: It's a shame it has to be attached to the equation in question and not a global option for the document.

Comment: @tmgriffiths You can make it global without the `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`. If you then want to revert your inline mathematics locally, just open a group and use `\let\sum\oldsum` and `\let\frac\oldfrac` to get the old definitions again.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear, my fault. I knew removing the `\*group`'s would render it global, but it would make `\sum` and `\frac` be display math in an inline environment. I'm just trying to figure out why there's inline math when it shold be display math.

Comment: @tmgriffiths Inside an array, math should be inline, not display. The concern inside array is that displaymath causes parts of the mathematics affected by the displaystyle command to overflow to the line above or below. Other than that, I'm unsure how to put your phrasing "It should be display math".

Comment: *Inside an array, math should be inline...* I didn't know that. That's where I've gone wrong. Thankyou. All the examples I came across when I went searching were simple equations, no `\sum`s, `\int`s or `\frac`s, so I never noticed that it was always Inline mode.

Comment: @tmgriffiths `array` is essentially designed for matrices and the like, you should be using a displayed alignment environment such as `aligned` from `amsmath` then entries will be in display math by default.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that maintains your basic `array` setup, while simplifying it somewhat. Inside the `equation`, it first defines two scratch macros, `\blocka` and `\blockb`, and then uses each of them twice: first to typeset the material itself, then as the argument of the `\vphantom` instructions. Each "block" macro consists of an `array` environment that contains two columns. Extra care is taken to align the `+` symbols and the summation symbols and to provide a bit of vertical whitespace between the two big blocks.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{mathtools,array}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for "\addlinespace" macro
\begin{document}
\hrule % just to illustrate width of text block
\begin{equation}
\setlength\extrarowheight{1ex}
    %% Set up two scratch macros, \blocka and \blockb, for the bonded 
    %% and non-bonded terms, respectively
    \newcommand\blocka{% bonded terms
    \begin{array}{r @{} >{\displaystyle}l} % 2nd column in displaystyle
         U  ={}& \phantom{+\quad}\smashoperator[l]{\sum_{\text{bonds},\, i}} K_{b,i} ( b_i - b_{0,i} )^2 \\
               &+\quad \smashoperator[l]{\sum_{\text{angles},\, i}}
                  K_{\theta,i} (\theta_i -\theta_{0,i})^2 \\
               &+\quad \smashoperator[l]{\sum_{\text{dihedrals},\, i}}
                  K_{\phi,i} ( 1 - \cos( n\phi_i - \phi_{0,i} ) ) \\
               &+\quad \smashoperator[l]{\sum_{%
                  \substack{\text{improper},\, i\\ \text{dihedrals}}}} 
                  K_{\omega,i} ( \omega_i - \omega_{0,i} )^2 \\
    \end{array}}
    \newcommand\blockb{% non-bonded terms
    \begin{array}{r @{} >{\displaystyle}l} % 2nd column in displaystyle
        \phantom{U  ={}}
            &+\quad \smashoperator[l]{\sum_{\text{atoms},\, i,j}} \epsilon_{ij}
                        \biggl[%
                              \biggl(%
                                \frac{ r^{\min}_{ij} } { r_{ij} }
                              \biggr)^{\!12}
                           -2 \biggl(
                                \frac{ r^{\min}_{ij} }{ r_{ij} }
                              \biggr)^{\!6} \,
                        \biggr] \\ \addlinespace
            &+\quad \smashoperator[l]{\sum_{\text{atoms},\, i,j}}
                        \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0\epsilon_r}
                        \frac{q_i q_j}{ r_{ij} }
   \end{array}}
   %% Now typeset the material in the two big blocks
   \begin{array}{ll} 
       \blocka & \left. \vphantom{\blocka} \right\} \text{bonded} \\ 
       \addlinespace
       \blockb & \left. \vphantom{\blockb} \right\} \text{non-bonded}
   \end{array}
   \end{equation}

\hrule  % just to illustrate width of text block
\end{document}
```